# how to differentiate between my Order Model and the order sql function in Asp.Net MVC view page

Tags: sql, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, razor

there seems to be a problem with my `query` statement in my `view page` for my reports. I'm unable to execute this `query` because (I think) my `Order` `table` is clashing with the `order sql statement function`.

Does any one know a solution to this? I know how to differentiate in the `query builder`, as it requires you to put the `table name` in `double quotations`, but now I'm trying to find out how to differentiate the table in `MVC View Razor Syntax.`

```
var Query = ("SELECT Hospital.Name,Hospital.Province,Count('Order'.OrderID) AS Orders FROM Hospital,'Order' WHERE Hospital.HospitalID = 'Order'.HospitalID GROUP BY Hospital.Name,Hospital.Province;");
```

Please take note that this query is in my view page **NOT** the query builder. If there is any additional information you require, please let me know.

Comment: If thats the case use`[order] ` - square brackets for the name of the table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If thats the case use `[order]` - square brackets with the name of the table as

```
select * from [order]
```

***Suggestion:*** Please Don't use anything the same as, or even similar to, a reserved word

Answer (score 0):

For Microsoft SQL Server, `[` and `]` are what's used by default to escape identifiers:

```
select [desc], [identity], boo, foo from [order]
```

This behavior is non-standard and can be changed to what is required by ANSI SQL with [`SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174393.aspx).

Overall, using reserved words as identifiers is something that should generally be avoided.